# Gulp task to merge JSON and Handlebars from partials into HTML

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js, gulp-data, gulp-compile-handlebars

I'm making a simple proof-of-concept website using JSON as a data source and Handlebars for a templating engine, with a view to 'merging' the two things into a static HTML file.

The website will be very modular, so each component will be built using a distinct Handlebars 'partial', which will each consume data from its own JSON file.

The development structure I have so far is like this:

```
src/
    models/
        header.json
        article.json
        footer.json

    partials/
        header.hbs
        article.hbs
        footer.hbs

    index.hbs
```

The contents of the index.hbs file is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{> header}}
    {{> article}}
    {{> footer}}
</body>
</html>
```

The partials are very simple for now.  e.g `header.hbs` contains:

```
<header>{{header}}</header>
```

I have the following gulp file `gulpfile.js` which goes part way to what I want to achieve:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var data = require('gulp-data');
var handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var templateData = {
        header: 'Welcome'
    },
    options = {
        batch : ['./src/partials']
    }

    return gulp.src('src/index.hbs')
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

So far, it bundles in my partials together and outputs everything nicely, as HTML, in a file called `dist/index.html`.

The thing that's missing is the JSON data part.  Currently the JSON data being consumed by the partials is defined in the gulp file (the variable `templateData`) but I want each partial to consume data from the `src/models` JSON files to provide clear separation.  The name of the JSON file will be identical to the name of the `.hbs` partial it's consumed by.

I'm unclear how to go about this.  The [gulp-compile-handlebars documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compile-handlebars) suggests that using gulp-data will support what I need, but I'm struggling to piece together anything from the [gulp-data documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data) that works for my specific use-case.

Could anyone please suggest how I could modify my gulp file to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but the solution to the problem was to ditch `gulp-compile-handlebars` and `gulp-data` and use `gulp-hb` instead, which allows for an array of JSON objects to be passed in to the templates and is generally more geared towards what I'm doing.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I've encountered the same problem and would love to see the solution you found posted as an answer to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Dan for the semi-solution as a comment!  Would love a more in-depth answer of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you can use gulp-data to return an object from your models .json file and it will be added to your tempateData object.

> Use gulp-data to pass a data object to the template based on the
>   handlebars file being processed. If you pass in template data this
>   will be extended with the object from gulp-data.

So this worked for me.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    var templateData = {
        header: 'Welcome'
    },
    options = {
        batch : ['./src/partials']
    }

    return gulp.src('src/index.hbs')
        .pipe(data(function(file) {
            return require('./src/models/test.json');
        }))
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

And you can modify the path to your .json file to match the name of the src .hbs file.

Comment: You don't specify how you access the passed object from the template file.